# Is there any idea to copy file to another windows server without share folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

In my application,I have to copy a whole directory to the specified location in remote servers, and now we first make the location in the remote servers shared,then copy it.

Furthermore,the location in the remote servers are all mapped to `web site` in iis. That's to say,each location is a web site root path in remote server,and directories copied to the server will be made as `` `application(vitrual directory) `` and deployed.

However,our clients wonder if this is security since the root of the `web site` location is shared?

So I wonder if there is any way we can copy files without share folder?

Comment: Off the top of my head, you can set NTFS permissions on web site root share, set up an (S)FTP server, or set up WebDAV.  I was a local admin on the servers I managed, and I would access the servers via `\\server\c$` to do file copies for web site updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394594%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394594(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could probably create a simple Wcf Service which could be hosted by the iis on the target server and give an opportunity to upload files. I guess the security issues (authentication, ip filtering, etc.) can be considered easily enough and the permissions to write files to the server will be necessary only for the wcf service, executing locally.